# JavaFX- MouseEvents converting the shapes from circle to a rectangle

Tags: java, javafx

I have been trying to convert the pre-made program on netbeans called MouseEvents shape from a circle to a rectangle. I tried it out but this is where I got a red line:

```
 private Rectangle createRectangle(final String name, final Color color, int width, int height) {
    //create a rectangle with desired name,  color and radius
    final Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(width, new RadialGradient(0, 0, 0.2, 0.3, 1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, new Stop[] {
        new Stop(0, Color.rgb(250,250,255)),
        new Stop(1, color)
    }));
```

Here is another bit of code that may help you answer:

```
 final Rectangle rectangleSmall = createRectangle("Blue rectangle", Color.DODGERBLUE, 25,10);
```

Comment: It's not clear what do u want and what problems are you getting.

Comment: @MDMuziburRahman I am getting a redline under new RadialGradient(0, 0, 0.2, 0.3, 1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, new Stop[] {
            new Stop(0, Color.rgb(250,250,255)),
            new Stop(1, color)
        }));                                                                                                      It says incompatible types: Radialgradient can not be converted to double

Comment: well, may be because you didn't use the 'height' variable at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's not clear whether you are converting a circle to rectangle or the vice versa, and what do u mean by 'converting' .

And also, you aren't creating a Rectangle at all, because, you didn't use the height variable at all. Try this instead:

```
final Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(width, height, new RadialGradient(0, 0, 0.2, 0.3, 1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, new Stop[] {
        new Stop(0, Color.rgb(250,250,255)),
        new Stop(1, color)
    });
```